# Gif does not appear when clicking button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is the code :

```
<button class="fun" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="emoji">Click For Fun!</button>
<div id="emoji" class="collapse">
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <img class="gif" src="img/gif/panda.gif">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The button has the data target set to "emoji" but when I click the button nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-target="#emoji"` will solve your problem.

> `<button class="fun" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#emoji">Click For Fun!</button>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button class="fun" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#emoji">Click For Fun!</button>
<div id="emoji" class="collapse">
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <img class="gif" src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/Tia2InBEWaQgckP3UG/source.gif">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```